# CSS transition running at the same time, instead of one after the other (accordion)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm building an accordion and having trouble with the CSS transitions, animating `max-height`

I want to animations of closing one item and opening the other to run at the same time, not one after another as it's currently happening.

Also, the closing transition is much slower than the opening one...

I have this running on a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrepadez/wchsj65b/25/)
but here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      Title 2
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      Title 3
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
      <p>kjshsdjkfhsdkfh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordion-item {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.accordion-title {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion-item.open .accordion-content {
  max-height: 500px; 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    if(target.classList.contains('accordion-title')){
    const opened = document.querySelector('.accordion-item.open')
    opened && opened.classList.remove('open')
    const parent = target.parentNode
    parent !== opened && parent.classList.add('open')
  }
})
```

Comment: They are running at the same time, but you don't see any displayed difference until `max-height` reaches the actual height. If the content for each was `500px` height, they would (visibly) animate together.

Comment: i understand... but then i have another problem because i want the height to be dynamic and the transition doesn't work with height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transitions are actually running at the same time, it only seems they do not.

The problem is that you are animating max-height from 0 to 500px, but actual height of your fully expanded accordion item is approximately 150px. Therefore the open animation has visible effect only at start, then it is "doing nothing" when going from 150 to 500px, while the closing animation starts and 500px and has no visible effect until it reaches 150px.

You have to choose a different approach to achieve what you want - you'll probably have to measure the element's expanded height, then set max-height (or just height) in the animation to that exact value.